# are there any cheap out of the box usb display adapters for ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

Are there any cheap out of the box USB display adapters for Ubuntu 14.04? Just simple plug and play. My 
Startech doesn't work i am looking for a cheap VGA adapter.

Comment: Do you have an hdmi out? There are some hdmi to vga adapters out there that don't require os compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like displaylink drivers have been included in the mainline kernel since 3.4. A quick search for 'displaylink "linux"' on google will give some helpful results.

Although, **it looks like Linux support for DL-3x00 or DL-41xx is not currently available.** [That may have changed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink#Linux) **However, there is now a driver [download for Ubuntu available from Displaylink](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu.php).**

There are also models available from [plugable](http://plugable.com/2014/03/06/displaylink-usb-2-0-graphics-adapters-on-linux-2014-edition). [See here for other info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169533/usb-to-vga-on-linux).

People were reporting issues back on Ubuntu versions 13.04 and 13.10 but the good news is that the fix was to use a newer kernel.

My suggestion would be to upgrade to the latest 14.04 hardware enablement stack to ensure the best performance. You can do so by running one of the following commands.

The [displaylink instructions](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/615714#ubuntu) say to use the utopic HWE (which was the latest at the time) so I have also included instructions on how to install the *current* HWE stack as it may work better:

For the vivid HWE stack:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid linux-signed-generic-lts-vivid
```

When you reboot, your machine will default to the newest kernel.

If you have any issues, you can choose 'advanced options' from the grub menu which will send you to another menu where you can choose which kernel to use.

[source 1](http://plugable.com/2014/03/06/displaylink-usb-2-0-graphics-adapters-on-linux-2014-edition)

[source 2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

and this really good answer: [USB to VGA on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169537/70847)